# Site.Master and hiding MenuItem problems

Tags: code-behind, menuitem, master-pages

What I wanted is to display different MenuItems from a Site.Master page depending on user role. Since I did not find how to do it, I created two site master pages - Site.Master and Acct_Site.Master. 
On Site.Master I have CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" and on Acct_Site.Master I have  CodeBehind="Acct_Site.master.cs". I put a break point on a first statement on Page_Load method in Site.Master.cs and in Acct_Site.master.cs.

On a first screen I program stop on a break in Site.Master.cs, but next it stops on a break in Site.Master.cs, but displays Acct_Site.Master. So it looks that Site.Master.cs is executed, even it is shows Acct_Site.Master.
Any Ideas why?

Thanks,

Zalek

Answer (score 0):

My mistake - I found the name Acct_Site.Master was an invalid name - it looks that we cannot add underscore to the name. I renamed Acct_Site.Master to AcctSite.Master and my program worked.

zalek